# Excel copy cell from a column if value is starting with Formula

Tags: excel, copy, formula

I have this kind of column in my Excel:

```
A              B
gbgdf,  
dsfsd,
gdgdf,
TC-EVTgfdsfs,
gdfgd,
```

I am willing to copy every cell that is **NOT** starting with 'TC-EVT'

I tried to use different formulas, such as:

```
LOOKUP
SWITCH
```

but with no success at all.

I need column B to look like this:

```
gbgdf,  
dsfsd,
gdgdf,
gdfgd,
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Try*** this formula, assuming you are using either **O365** or **Excel 2021**

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=FILTER(A1:A5,LEFT(A1:A5,6)<>"TC-EVT")
```

Or,

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=FILTER(A1:A5,NOT(LEFT(A1:A5,6)="TC-EVT"))
```

Comment: Yeah truly sir, I overlooked that, will make the necessary changes.! Sir, but if the instance is 1 then?

Comment: @JvdV Sir, may use this one as well, `=FILTER(A1:A5,IFERROR(FIND("TC-EVT",A1:A5,1),0)<=1)` though not required still an option, what do you think sir, your advice is highly welcomed.

Comment: Yeah, multiple ways leading to rome, personally I'd say `=FILTER(A1:A5,LEFT(A1:A5,6)<>"TC-EVT")` covers it.

Answer (score 0):

**THE ANSWER I FOUND TO BE PERFECTLY WORK:**

```
=FILTER(A1:A5,NOT(LEFT(A1:A5,6)="TC-EVT"))
```